# Rule failed when generating expression for Constraint and constructing component from data=none failed Errors While Using PYOMO

Tags: python, constraints, pyomo

I am trying to do a linear programming using PYOMO and the constraint function keeps giving me errors.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.read_csv(r'Data\prostate.csv')
data.head()
data['y'] = data.loc[:, 'lpsa'] # duplicating lpsa and name the new column y
y = data.loc[:, ['y']] # make y into its own dataframe called y
del data['lpsa'] # delete lpsa from the original dataframe
data['intercept'] = '1.0' # add a new column called intercept with 1.0s for all rows
features = data.loc[:, ['lcavol', 'lweight', 'age', 'lbph', 'svi', 'lcp', 'gleason', 'pgg45', 'intercept']] # make all other columns including intercept column into a dataframe called features
```

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo
model = pyo.ConcreteModel()
N = list(range(1, len(data)))

model.r_pos = pyo.Var(N, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)
model.r_neg = pyo.Var(N, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)
model.beta = pyo.Var(features)

def abs_rule(model, i):
    expression = y[i-1] - sum(data.loc[i-1, features] * model.beta[features] for feature in features) == model.r_pos[i] - model.r_neg[i]
    return expression

model.abs = pyo.Constraint(N, rule=abs_rule)
model.L1_objective = pyo.Objective(expr = sum((model.r_pos[i] + model.r_neg[i]) for i in N))
```

```
ERROR: Rule failed when generating expression for Constraint abs with index 1:
    KeyError: 0
ERROR: Constructing component 'abs' from data=None failed: KeyError: 0
```

Not sure what I am missing here. Please advice. Thank you.

Comment: It is tough to tell because you don't include enough data to replicate the problem.  A "good" question includes a snippet or example data that can reproduce the error, so you might want to mock up a couple rows.  that said, the error says there is a Key Error: 0.  So you are trying to pull the "0" indexed thing out of something that doesn't have it.  Looking at the equation, that is likely `y`

Comment: If you are just getting going w/ `pyomo`, I'd recommend you move away from `pandas` for a bit and put all of the parameters into model parameters...much easier to inspect the problem as you build it!

Comment: I am not sure if Python has bulid-in datasets, but I didn't have to load any other data file. The prostate.csv file just loaded with the current code.

Comment: The error you are having likely depends on ‘y’ which depends on the data set what you do not provide so it is tough to figure out what is going on.  Trim the data set down to something that produces the error and provide it.

Comment: AirSquid, I think you might be right. The problem is if I define y using y = data.loc[:, ['y']], y is now in its own data frame, but the y below in this part of the code is still not working, expression = y[i-1] - sum(data.loc[i-1, features] * model.beta[features] for feature in features) == model.r_pos[i] - model.r_neg[i]. What else could I be missing here?